# Resizing remote images and saving it to the server

Tags: php, html, forms, input

So i made use of [this guide](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) and was able to come up with this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="image"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and process.php i came up with:

```
 <?php
   include("SimpleImage.php");
   $imgName = $_GET["image"]; //assuming you used GET request and form submits to http://url/script.php?image=something.jpg
   $image = new SimpleImage();
   $image->load($imgName);
   $image->resizeToWidth(250);
   $image->save($imgName);
   echo $imgName;
?>
```

However something's wrong. It's not saving the image :( I'm completely a PHP noob so i hope you can give some newbie friendly solutions. Thank YOu :)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but if `$imgName` refers to an image on a remote server, then wouldn't `$image->save($imgName)` be trying to *save* it to a remote server?

Comment: When you say it's not saving, what is it doing? Are you getting an error or is the image file just not appearing? What is being echoed in your $imgName?

Comment: what should i do then? I'm just getting a blank page after loading process.php

Answer (score 0):

check your folder/file permission if you are able to read/write on that directory.
If you have not set a path on where to save the new image,  usually it writes to the same directory where your process.php is located.